# Can't import JS module in Laravel blade script tag

Tags: javascript, laravel, import, export, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel project. in **resource/js/app.js** I have a Vue instance and when I want to read or write `vm` in my blade, I just can't! I think this is because of my webpack.mix.js but I can't figure out what is the exact cause.

***resources/js/app.js:***

```
let vm = new Vue({
 data() {
  return {
   order: {
    isOrgan: false
   }
  };
 },
 router,
 store
}).$mount('#app')

export default vm;
```

***resources/views/app.blade.php:***

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>

<script type="module">
 import vm from '/js/app.js';
 console.log(vm);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` is CommonJS and is not available in browsers, that's why it does not work. If you absolutely want to do `console.log(vm)` outside of your `app.js`, you need to do this

```js
window.vm = new Vue({
 data() {
  return {
   order: {
    isOrgan: false
   }
  };
 },
 router,
 store
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then your `console.log(vm)` (implicitly `console.log(window.wm)`) will work.